# How to track user activity on the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I have an S3 bucket with requester pays, is there anyway I can get data on who is downloading what? Is there another option? Need users to pay for egress but need to know who they are. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From [Requester Pays Buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html):

> In general, bucket owners pay for all Amazon S3 storage and data transfer costs associated with their bucket. A bucket owner, however, can configure a bucket to be a Requester Pays bucket. With Requester Pays buckets, the requester instead of the bucket owner pays the cost of the request and the data download from the bucket. The bucket owner always pays the cost of storing data.

So, AWS will automatically charge users for egress. You will only pay the cost of storing data.

If you wish to obtain a log of requests to the bucket, you can use [Server Access Logging for an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/server-access-logging.html).

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. My question is though whether I can somehow track those users? Under Requester pays. For example where the IP is coming from? Or any form of data. AWS only gives me a requester ID, which is not very useful at all. Trying to figure out how to have a requester pays and track the requester?

Comment: The Server Access Logs provide a **Remote IP** that you could use with an IP lookup service like Maxmind. An alternative is to activate [Amazon S3 Object-Level Actions in AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html), which provides richer information, especially since Requester Pays requires an authenticated user, so CloudTrail can probably provide some details of their AWS Account.

Comment: Oh really! Even if it’s requester pays? Thank you! Thank you. I will research this further.